# Is there a difference in the ways of converting from integer to integer?

Tags: c#, c++, casting, bit-manipulation, d

Is there a difference when I want to convert an integer(for example 32-bit integer/int) to another integer type(for example 8-bit integer/byte). Here is some example code for the two ways I can convert it:

```
byte foo(int value)
{
    //return value; <-- this causes problems because I need to convert it to byte

   //First way(most people use this):
   return (byte)value; //this involves casting the value and also works if value is floating point type

   //Second way:
   return value & byte.MaxValue; //byte.MaxValue is a constant that is 255
}
```

So is there any difference between the two? I know that bitwise operations only work for integer types. I know that the second way is not quite readable or recommended. Except that is there any difference of the output of both ways. That is not only for int and byte, but for every integer-integer type combination.

Ok so it seems that this operation has a different behaviour in different languages. I wan't to see the differences, so please post answers for C++/C#/D.

Also I forgot I meant unsigned integers only(not signed). So it is for all unsigned integer types.

Comment: What's a `byte`? Edit: Oh it's tagged as C# too. The answers for each language are likely to be different.

Comment: It does not make sence to me to be different for each language. It is more of a teoretical question.

Comment: @Bosak: Whether it makes sense to you or not, it *does* depend on the language. Different languages can have subtly different rules for this. For example, in C# the cast can throw an exception *if* you're in a checked context.

Comment: `value & byte.MaxValue;` is still an `int`. Don't you need an explicit conversion in C# then?

Comment: @DanielFischer I have tested this in D and it was a `byte` after the operation.

Comment: Well, considering that `return value & byte.MaxValue` results in a compiler error in C#, I'd say that you're best off using the cast in that language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, casting an int to a byte will throw an exception if it is out of range *and* within a `checked` context. Otherwise, casting acts pretty much like C++ does.

The type promotion works in C# like it does in C++ (as described by Mark B).

For comparison, look at the IL generated by these three methods:

```
byte foo1(uint value)
{
    return (byte) value;
}

.method private hidebysig instance uint8 foo1(int32 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.1 
    L_0001: conv.u1 
    L_0002: ret 
}
```

Versus

```
byte foo2(uint value)
{
    checked
    {
        return (byte)value;
    }
}

.method private hidebysig instance uint8 foo2(uint32 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.1 
    L_0001: conv.ovf.u1.un 
    L_0002: ret 
}
```

And for the ANDing:

```
byte foo3(int value)
{
    return (byte)(value & byte.MaxValue);
}

.method private hidebysig instance uint8 foo3(uint32 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.1 
    L_0001: ldc.i4 255
    L_0006: and 
    L_0007: conv.u1 
    L_0008: ret 
}
```

This again uses `conv.u1`, like the first method, so all it does is introduce the overhead of anding off the extra bits that are ignored by the `conv.u1` instruction anyway.

Therefore in C# I would just use the casting if you don't care about range checking.

One interesting thing is that in C#, this will give you a compiler error:

```
Trace.Assert(((byte)256) == 0); // Compiler knows 256 is out of range.
```

This won't give a compile error:

```
int value = 256;
Trace.Assert(((byte)value) == 0); // Compiler doesn't care.
```

And of course this won't give a compile error either:

```
unchecked
{
    Trace.Assert(((byte)256) == 0);
}
```

It's odd that the first one gives a compiler error even though by default it's unchecked at runtime. I guess compile-time is checked by default!

Comment: what happens then if I do both `(byte)(value & byte.MaxValue)`? Will it ensure it never goes out of range?

Comment: @Bosak Yes, that would ensure that the cast can't fail in a checked context.

Comment: @Bosak Yes, but you wouldn't do that. You'd just cast it and use `unchecked` with it if you weren't sure it was being called from an `unchecked` context.

Comment: And what happens if the value is out of range in unchecked context? In both casting and in bitwise and and then casting. For example if I have `value = 256` then `256 & 255 = 0`(not sure about that) and `(byte)256 = 0`. I am not sure about both cases please corect me.

Comment: @Bosak If it's out of range in an unchecked context it ignores the bits other than bits 0..7, so it's exactly the same as if you anded it with 0xFF first. `((byte)256) == 0` indeed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson so there is no difference in the result using both ways. Also it is strange because in D when I did this: `return value & ubyte.max;` without casting it worked.(the function's return value was also ubyte). But that is probably going offtopic and maybe I should ask another question regarding D only.

Comment: @Bosak That's correct - there's no difference (unless using `checked`)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there is absolutely a difference in how the result is obtained, because operands to `&` will be promoted to the size of the larger of the two types. If the "max" value you `&` with happens to be signed, then you'll sign extend and the bitwise operation will not be likely to have the desired effects.

I would personally prefer the explicit `return static_cast<char>(value);`

Comment: oh sorry I didn't mention I meant for unsigned integers only